# How to open Samsung Oculus / Gear VR app by an intent from my app?

Tags: android, oculus, gear-vr, samsung-mobile-sdk

I want to launch an activity in a `Gear VR` app

Do I use intents with `URI`? for example if I want to open a map with lat long I would write something similar

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

How to open `Samsung Gear VR / Oculus` app by an intent from my android app?

Comment: any chance you figured that out? If so, please post an answer for your own question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per oculus, It is not a allowed behavior. Check the following link.
https://forums.oculusvr.com/community/discussion/comment/619743#Comment_619743